# MIDI Patchbay for Windows? / How to send MIDI from app to Reason in real-time on WinXP

Tags: midi

[MIDI Patchbay](http://notahat.com/midi_patchbay) is a utility for Mac OSX that lets you pass MIDI data between musical hardware and software.

**Is there an equivalent utility for Windows operating systems?** 
(I've done due diligence, and haven't found anything worthwhile)

*My use case:* I'd like to write a program that generates MIDI data and sends it to Propellerhead Reason in real-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIDI Yoke is definitely useful for this, but another option is to use the [virtualMIDI driver by Tobias Erichsen](http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/virtualMIDI.html).  It is quite handy.

Answer (score 4):

I have a feeling that MIDI-OX or MIDI Yoke from [midiox](http://www.midiox.com/) can do this

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I use all of them. To add a penny don't forget to try [Soundigy Midi Patchbay](http://www.soundigy.com/midipatchbay.php). It's free (they also offer paid version - Midi Patchbay Extended, and Midi Processor, but that's the software of other sort...).